# Alternate of CoApp (3rd party tool for making NuGet packages from within a build directory)

Tags: powershell, package, package-managers

I am looking to replace CoApp because CoApp is no longer supported. I have explored few alternatives but they seems to be more aimed at installing and uninstalling software than creating and consuming packages in a build environment.

So need any suggestions on alternative of CoApp.

Comment: Did you find any alternate?